# Does GW provides OOTB Restful Service for creating a Submission like it provides SOAP service for creating Submission?

Tags: rest, submission, guidewire

Does GW provides OOTB Restful Service for creating a Submission like it provides SOAP service for creating Submission? If so which Guidewire version provides it

I am looking for OOTB Restful Service for creating a Submission like it provides SOAP service for creating Submission

Answer (score 8):

This functionality is available for customers on the Guidewire Cloud Platform, and not present for self-managed customers. There is a generic, product-neutral {pc_base_url}/rest/job/v1/submissions endpoint to which you'd submit a POST request. The body of the request will contain pertinent information such as account, base state, effective date, producer code, and product. This is functionally equivalent to what the New Submission UI does in PolicyCenter.

Product-specific rest apis are also generated for each product (such as Personal Auto, Commercial Property, etc) which include the ability to populate submissions, as well as all other policy transactions for Guidewire Cloud Platform customers.

These apis are distinct for each product because there are product/line specific details such as what coverables exist, what exposures exist, what type of location information is available, etc. As I'm sure you've seen, these vary wildly by product. This makes a generic ability to build submissions not plausible. Instead we generate a number of endpoints that are children of the  /rest/job/v1/job endpoint which allow you to access every element of the policy data hierarchically. So a call to create a driver to a vehicle on a personal auto policy might look something like this:

`{pc_base_url}/rest/job/v1/jobs/{{currentSubmissionId}}/lines/PersonalAutoLine/personal-vehicles/{{currentVehicleID}}/vehicle-drivers`

and have a body specifying information about the driver such as percentage driven.

These apis are generated off of APD products using a code generator built into the PolicyCenter Product Management UI. For externally managed products such as legacy products build prior to APD, or the old out-of-the-box products, or Standards Based Template Commercial lines, one must do what we call a "Cloud Retrofit" with the product to generate these APIs.

A Cloud Retrofit entails exporting an XMind template based on the externally managed line, importing it as a new APD line, and then running the same code generator used for native APD lines. This process can be somewhat complex, requiring some manual massaging of the template generator's configuration file due to some functional differences between APD and the legacy product designer. In some cases, the APD code generator's functionality is augmented by a product known as the "Rest Endpoint Generator", which unlike the APD API generator, is not PolicyCenter-specific.

For more information, see the following sections in your Guidewire Product Documentation:

"Cloud API Consumer Guide"
"Generating LOB-specific endpoints"
"The REST endpoint generator"